# JQuery onclick event not working with created ID

Tags: jquery

I created an ID and in my a element to hook it to an click event which should change my css on click.

Here is the code

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".has-posts > a").attr("id","MyNewID");
        $("#MyNewID").click(function(){ $('#az-slider').css("background","yellow"); });
    });
</script>
```

im not sure what's wrong, it creates the ID but the event does not work

Comment: Does only one element has `#MyNewID` or there's multiple elements with the same id?'

Comment: Id selector `$("#MyNewID")` will only select first element with `id` as `MyNewID`. So all other elements with `id` as `MyNewID` will not get assign `click` event.

Comment: Use $(document).on('click',"#MyNewID",function(){});

Comment: You can use `attribute` `selector` like `$("[id=MyNewID]").click(...)`

Comment: `$(".has-posts > a").attr("id","MyNewID");` Maybe `.has-posts > a` can select serveral elements if there are. Then more than 2 elements have the same id as `MyNewID`. In this case, $("#MyNewID") will not work because ID should be unique on  the page. It cannot be assigned to more than 2. What do you get when you `console.log($("#MyNewID"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to attach click event handler using `on` as shown below and make sure that all created ids should be unique through out the document

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".has-posts > a").attr("id","MyNewID");
        $(document).on('click',"#MyNewID", function(){ 
           $('#az-slider').css("background","yellow"); 
        });
    });
</script>
```